# Angular binding causing Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: angularjs, rxjs, rxjs5

I have a very simple component, something like

```
App.component('mxComponentOverlay', {
  template: '<div></div>',

  bindings: {
    input: '=?',
  },

  controller: ComponentOverlay,
});
```

Input is an object, so I am doing:

```
  <mx-component-overlay
     input="{ 'icon': 'add', 'subject': $ctrl.subject }">
  </mx-component-overlay>
```

`$ctrl.subject` was an RxJS 4, Subject, migrating to RxJS 5 this is causing a `Maximum call stack size exceeded` error.

If I do:

```
  <mx-component-overlay
     input="$ctrl.subject">
  </mx-component-overlay>
```

I dont have the issue. Any idea what can cause this?

**UPDATE**

[jsbin that reproduces the issue](https://jsbin.com/juzesaroja/1/edit?html,js,console)

Comment: I guess `input: '>?',`(uni directional flow) should work, also it make sense here

Comment: @PankajParkar if you mean `<?`, it doesnt fix the issue